# Pine Script- Is there any function to check a certain order is filled or not yet?

Tags: pine-script

Is there any function, or any possible way to check a certain order is filled or not yet?
For example, I give the id of a limit/stop order then the function checks and returns true or false to tell me whether the order is filled or not yet?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No. That information has to be derived using variables like `strategy.opentrades`, `strategy.position_avg_price` or `strategy.position_size`.

Answer (score 0):

look at strategy.closedtrades
when it changes, an order has been closed.

e.g strategy.closedtrades!=strategy.closedtrades[1]